# From Action Script 2.0 to 3.0 compiling errors

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

[From the errors above what should I change in the code? I'm new to AS3 and a point in the right direction will help a lot, thanks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiQ1a.png)

Scene 1, Layer 'Script Layer', Frame 18, Line 62, Column 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before add.

Scene 1, Layer 'Script Layer', Frame 18, Line 62, Column 29 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before eq.

Scene 1, Layer 'Script Layer', Frame 18, Line 68, Column 24 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before add.

Scene 1, Layer 'Script Layer', Frame 18, Line 68, Column 48 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before rightparen.

```
   leng = 52;
   q = 0;
   while(Number(q) < Number(leng))
   {
      rand = random(52);
      if(eval("c" add rand) eq "empty")
      {
         q = q - 1;
      }
      else
      {
         set("shuffle" add q,eval("c" add rand));
         set("c" add rand,"empty");
      }
      q = Number(q) + 1;
   }
  q = 0;
}
ShufflePloy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about AS2, but first I'd try changing `rand = random(52);` to:

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*52);
```

and then `if(eval("c" add rand) eq "empty")`

to

```
if(this["c"+rand] == "empty")
```

and the contents of the else block to

```
this["shuffle"+q] = this["c"+rand];
this["c"+rand] = "empty";
```